# Get the least significant bit of a number in Scheme

Tags: scheme, bit-manipulation

How do I get the least significant bit of a (whole) number in Scheme?
Is this a fairly easy thing todo?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't have scheme handy to make sure I've got it right, but won't `(define lsb n) (modulo n 2))` work?

Comment: Yes, that works. Another way to do this would be: `(define (lsb n) (- n (bitwise-and n (- n 1))))` But the reason I even asked about this at all is which one of the two method is more efficient. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1508893 That looks awfully complicated. Why not just `(bitwise-and n 1)`?

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, code it up and profile it.  It's usually surprising where your time is really going and it's the only real way to answer questions about which way is faster.  People have found some interesting surprises in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Scheme implementation supports [SRFI 60](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-60/srfi-60.html), you can simply use:

```
(logand n 1)
```

(`bitwise-and` is a synonym that some Scheme implementations prefer, so if you don't have `logand`, check for `bitwise-and` too.)

Otherwise, if you are willing to assume you're on a [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system (all mainstream platforms are), you can also use `odd?` or `even?`:

```
(if (odd? n) 1 0)
```

Comment: Right, I wasn't aware `odd?` and `even?` were built-in